# How to get the 'text' value return from 'Textbox'?

Tags: c#, textbox, white-framework

I am writing scripts using White for UI automation testing. I need to get the actual text value return from a'Textbox'.

I used the following line to search the TextBox first, the AutomationId ("vwSearched_Number") represent the actual text value (e.g. 123456). I want to get this text value (123456) returned to be used for next method. But the script failed with the error msg from Assert validation which means no 'SearchedNumber' value returned.

```
  TextBox SearchedNumber = MainWindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("vwSearched_Number"));

   Assert.IsNotNull(SearchedNumber, "SearchedNumber is not valid");
```

Comment: You should probably add a tag for the language you're using, as it's not clear (to me at least) from the question.

Comment: @Herms: It's C#. Unfortunately, I have to few reputation points to add it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MainWindow.Get() function is returning a TextBox.. so SearchedNumber.Text should get you what you want.